# unzip files using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to unzip files using typescript. I have test.ts like below

```
var unzip = require('unzip-stream');
var fs = require('fs-extra'); 

class test {
  unzipp() {
    return fs.createReadStream('./e2e/chrome.zip').pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: './e2e' }));
  }
}
```

But when I run

```
tsc test.ts
```

and then

```
node test.js
```

nothing happens.

Can anyone  help with that please?

Comment: You have declared a class with a member method. Basically, you're telling node "I want to define this class that does something, then that's it. Don't do anything else. Just exit."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have declared your class but you did not run it.

```
var myInstance = new test();
myInstance.unzipp();
```

Answer (score 1):

As Patrick says in the comment, you're not actually running the code. You don't really need a class for this right now either. Try the following:

```
var unzip = require('unzip-stream');
var fs = require('fs-extra'); 

function unzip() {
  return fs.createReadStream('./e2e/chrome.zip').pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: './e2e' }));
}

unzip();
```